# How to install Windows 7 on notebook with Ubuntu preinstalled?

Tags: drivers, partitioning, windows-7, hardware, boot-repair

How to install Windows 7 on [notebook](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15-3543-laptop/pd) with Ubuntu preinstalled? New notebook come with Ubuntu preinstalled. I want replace Ubuntu with Windows 7 (not dual boot). I have Windows 7 .iso image on DVD. Also, what is common partitioning scheme for Windows 7, for hard drive 500GB?

P.S. Windows 7 should recognize Linux file system on hard drive without a problem? No need to clean out anything? Only Windows-7 will be installed, no Ubuntu on notebook is needed.

Comment: I think this question is more suited to http://superuser.com/ as it's really a Windows question.

Comment: Just make sure you have a Live Ubuntu medium after Win7 install, because Win7 bootlader will mess the GRUB (Ubuntu's bootloader) and you'll need to fix that in order to use both Win7 AND Ubuntu again.  

How to repair GRUB after Win install? Can find it in here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/398859/recovering-grub-after-installing-windows-7-with-boot-repair.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I install Windows after I've installed Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

Answer (score 2):

Just boot from the Windows DVD, select and delete the existing partitions and then create 1 big NTFS partition for the new Windows installation.

You could for sure create several partitions on that 500GB disk - but there is no clear advantage in doing that.

[This page](http://windows7.windowsreinstall.com/indexinstallguides.htm) offers install guides for Windows 7